# Using PowerShell with cookies

Tags: windows, cookies, windows-7, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to manipulate cookies on a PC using powershell. What I managed so far was

```
$p1 = "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\"
$ret = Get-Childitem $p1 -force
$ret
```

It took my a while to find out `-force` finds system hidden files but even so it's not displaying anything like the full list of stuff that navigating to the same location in Windows Explorer shows. What am I missing?

NB: I'm a real PowerShell neophyte, I'll probably have to search any cmdlet/property mentioned in an answer to figure out what has been said

Answer (score 0):

IE/Edge Cookies are not really saved to the "\Temporary Internet Files\" Folder. They life in the "\cookies\" folder. This folder can be dynamic (set and changed per profile).

Check out [this solution](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/04/26/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-my-internet-cookies/) from the ScriptingGuy. It has some example code to get the current folder from the reistry also.

Comment: Thankyou, however that example is VBScript not PowerShell

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, my fault. About 90%+ of "Hey, Scripting Guy" articles are PS nowadays, so I somehow ignored the str-Variables. But the direction this solution points to is correct ...

Comment: That's probably fair, but off the hoof I've no idea how to use that VBScript to inform writing a PowerShell one. I'll be able to spend some time searching and trying on Friday probably.